# Function to model deformed spacetime in 2D visualization of an Alcubierre drive

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, warp-drives

In the Wikipedia article on [Alcubierre drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) there is a top image. It is 2D visualization of an Alcubierre drive, showing the opposing regions of expanding and contracting space-time that displace the central region. **What is the function plotted in this image and how one can derive it?**

[image]

Comment: Looks faked. It's probably something like $xe^{-100(1-x^2-y^2)^2}$. Having said that, everything about the Alcubierre drive is fake physics, so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely revised answer.

That figure can be found at the end of Alcubierre's [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0009013v1.pdf) as Fig 1 with caption "Expansion of the normal volume elements". The "axes" seem to be "x" and "$\rho$" (mass density?).
In White's [paper](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110015936.pdf) on page 17 the figure is described as York Time and the corresponding equation is given.

York time is described in this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warp-field_experiments)